# Unexpectedly Stopped Running after Closing an App Window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, popupwindow

I am writing a vb script below to close an IE popup message with title "Error".

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.AppActivate("Error") 
wshShell.SendKeys "{Enter}" 
MsgBox "Closed"
```

The above code is able to successfully close the popup by sending Enter key to it. However, the next line MsgBox "Closed" is never executed. Why is this so? What do I need to do to make it work?

When I tried to send Tab key instead of Enter, the MsgBox appears as intended. I am suspecting that something has happened when the Enter key successfully closed the Error window and thus prevented the last line to be executed.

After inserting a delay or any code line in between the sendkey and the msg box, I am able to get the msg box to come out. However, I noted that that I am then unable to close the msg box after waiting for at least 20 seconds. I noted that this only happens when I try to close the IE Error window. When I try with other local Windows, I can close the MsgBox. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

It is because that the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key immediately closes two windows. You should add a sleep for a few seconds between two tasks.

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") wshShell.AppActivate("Error") 
Wscript.Sleep 4000
wshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
Wscript.Sleep 2000
MsgBox "Closed"
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif for replying but still the last line did not get executed. I tried the same closing Notepad windows as well. The codes are able to close them but the last line is skipped still.

Comment: Hi Wasif. That works. But I noticed that the line Wscript.Sleep 2000 can be just anything and it still works so something is very funny here. For instance, replacing the line with MsgBox "Test" and executing the code, I get the last line to come out but the Test message box never appears. Do you know why it functions this way?

Comment: Because we have to insert delays before every message boxes. Otherwise message boxes will behave crazy. Please accept the answer by clicking the grey tick mark

Comment: Inserting a delay does not seem to be the reason to cause the msgbox to appear as it rather seems that the script wants to skip the line below the SendKeys method line instead so I am still in doubt on how it behaves this way.

Comment: Try to debug the code line by line to see whether it is showing the message after sendkeys with Enter or not. Try to replace msgbox with debug.print to see whether it print the msg in console or not.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question. So it seems that the AppActivate method is the culprit. As the server fails to response in time, it hangs the script for an extended period of time.

So instead of closing the window with AppActivate and SendKeys, replacing them with Task Kill is the best solution:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run "cmd /c taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Error""", 0, True
MsgBox "Closed"
```

With this the MsgBox appears and I can click Ok to close it immediately afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.